# python if elif function returns wrong value

Tags: python

I have programmed a function in where I check the mouse position and if it is between some coordinates it should return a specific value. My problem is, that it does not return the corret value.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))

def volume(mouse):
    #print(mouse[0])
    if mouse[0] < 679:
        print("0")
        return 0
    if mouse[0] > 679 <= 738:
        print("0.1")
        return 0.1
    if mouse[0] > 738 <= 797:
        print("0.2")
        return 0.2
    if mouse[0] > 797 <= 856:
        print("0.3")
        return 0.3
    if mouse[0] > 856 <= 915:
        print("0.4")
        return 0.4
    if mouse[0] > 915 <= 975:
        return 0.5
    if mouse[0] > 975 <= 1035:
        return 0.6
    if mouse[0] > 1035 <= 1094:
        return 0.7
    if mouse[0] > 1094 <= 1157:
        return 0.8
    if mouse[0] > 1157 <= 1217:
        return 0.9
    if mouse[0] > 1217 <= 1277:
        return 1

while True:
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print(volume(mouse_pos))
```

I just wanted to say that this is a snipped out of a larger code.

##### updated code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))

def volume(mouse):
    #print(mouse[0])
    if mouse[0] < 679:
        return 0
    elif 679 > mouse[0] <= 738:
        return 0.1
    elif 738 > mouse[0] <= 797:
        return 0.2
    elif 797 > mouse[0] <= 856:
        return 0.3
    elif 856 > mouse[0] <= 915:
        return 0.4
    elif 915 > mouse[0] <= 975:
        return 0.5
    elif 975 > mouse[0] <= 1035:
        return 0.6
    elif 1035 > mouse[0] <= 1094:
        return 0.7
    elif 1094 > mouse[0] <= 1157:
        return 0.8
    elif 1157 > mouse[0] <= 1217:
        return 0.9
    elif mouse[0] > 1217:
        return 1

while True:
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print(volume(mouse_pos))
```

Comment: `mouse[0] > 679 <= 738` is equivalent to `(mouse[0] > 679) and (679 <= 738)`, which I don't think is quite what you intended.  Try `679 < mouse[0] <= 738`.

Comment: or use `elif` and just test the next upper bound, since the previous `if` limits the lower bound.

Comment: Note that you're also missing the `==` condition. What should happen when `mouse[0] == 679`?

Comment: Oh I guess not it works, but sometimes the type of 'volume()' is none. That is a problem, because in my main code I want to use the value of 'volume()' and if it is none, I will get an error.

Comment: your have regular increments of 60 units. The whole bunch of conditionals can be reduced to a simple equation

Comment: I now found out, that when I move my mouse to a specific x coordinate, my functions returns none. This coordinate is at roundabout 1150.

Comment: Do you mean `679 < mouse[0] <= 738` instead of `679 > mouse[0] <= 738`? (the same for each elif clause)

Comment: Yes, I need to change that tho. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is best implement as "table driven". I.e., minimal code that navigates some form of "map". In this case you could do this:

```
MAP = [
    679,
    738,
    797,
    856,
    915,
    975,
    1035,
    1094,
    1157,
    1217
    ]

def volume(coords):
    if coords:
        lo = float('-inf')
        x, *_ = coords
        for i, hi in enumerate(MAP):
            if lo < x <= hi:
                return 0.1 * i
            lo = hi
        return 1.0
```

Of course, if the intervals were all the same then you could do this mathematically but they're not

Comment: Wow this looks like a good way to do this. I am going to use this one. Thank you!